# Why does the drag-and-drop toolbox in Asp.net core not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have tried the drag-and-drop toolbox but this doesn't work. It has like invisible. I am new to ASP.NET.

[image]

Comment: There's no visual designer for mvc , and no drag and drop designer. That feature only worked for web form applications.  You have to run that page to see the results of your markup. While one of the newest features in vs2022 is the way cool live preview,  that newest feature is for web forms only.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are running a MVC Web Application and the toolbox shown is for ASP.NET WebForms Application(older technology). That's why its disabled

Example of an ASP.NET WebForms Control

```
<asp:AdRotator runat="server" AdvertisementFile="adfile.xml" Target="_blank" />
```

Side note, Always use HTML and CSS to position controls on a web page